# what does this [] syntax mean?

Tags: java

What does `[1]` at the end of statement mean?

```
String magnitudeString = details.split(" ")[1];
```

Can't it be written like this:

```
String [] magnitudeString = details.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[1]` is indexing an array: the result of [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is an array, and `[1]` is taking the second element from that result.

This is equivalent to:

```
String strs[] = details.split(" ");
String magnitudeString = strs[1];
```

So it can't be re-written quite like your suggestion.

Obviously either of these is a problem if the result of `split` has fewer than 2 elements, so a `length` check before accessing array elements is prudent, and the immediate form won't allow this.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that the `split()` method is going to return an array, and you are assigning the content at the second index of that array to your `String magnitudeString`(keep in mind that indexes start from 0 in Java).

Answer (score 0):

It's index of the String[] array that is returned by `details.split(" ")`.

One suggestion use

`String [] magnitudeString = details.split(" ");`
and iterate through.

using

> String magnitudeString = details.split(" ")[1]

may give run time exception of `array index out of bound`